# Pop-up window in ASP.NET `Page_Load` method

Tags: asp.net

I have a website. While the user is logged in, all reminder messages should pop up. I don't know how to code this. I've used `AjaxControlToolkit` on my page. All tools are added in the toolbox. I can't, however, drag the controls onto the page. How can I resolve these two issues?

Comment: you can use javaScript alert or ajaxpopup in your page load to show your remainders. 2. is the ajax controls enabled in ToolBox ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Ajax  **Model Pop up extender**

These Links may help you.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24924/Login-SignUp-Screen-Using-AJAX-ModalPopupExtender

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend the use of jQuery UI.  It's so easy to create popup dialog boxes.  See http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

On document load the popup would appear:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
```